# I can not access data from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a problem I can not access the data of a JSON object, it returns Object Object when using "each"

```
function NumeroConos(id_cono) {
  var ParamObjSend = {
    'id_cono' :id_cono,
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>AgregarOTController/NumeroConos",
    data: ParamObjSend,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(objView) {
      var items = objView.NumeroConos[0].numero_conos.split(';');

      $.each(items, function (ind, elem) {
        var option         = document.createElement('option');
        option.value       = $(this);
        option.textContent = $(this);
        $('#numero_conos').append(option);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

[image: output - Object Object]

JSON

```
{
  "success": true,
  "NumeroConos": [
    {
      "id_cono": "1",
      "descripcion_cono": "sdfasdf",
      "color_cono": "Rojo",
      "numero_conos": "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50",
      "token": "GcKegUhEh7kQAsf35fefkPmBMhwyKQvBFBcJ1W5z720xk9uegy",
      "estado": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: use `elem` instead of `$(this)` - since `$(this)` returns a jQuery object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, suggested by  ***ajai Jothi*** in the comment, solves your issue.

Instead, if you want to take advantage of how [jQuery Creates New Elements](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) on the fly you may write in a reduced format:

```
$.each(items, function (ind, elem) {
    $('#numero_conos').append($('<option/>', {value: elem, text: elem}));
});
```

The example:

```js
var objView = {"success":true,"NumeroConos":[{"id_cono":"1","descripcion_cono":"sdfasdf","color_cono":"Rojo","numero_conos":"1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50","token":"GcKegUhEh7kQAsf35fefkPmBMhwyKQvBFBcJ1W5z720xk9uegy","estado":"0"}]};


var items = objView.NumeroConos[0].numero_conos.split(';');

$.each(items, function (ind, elem) {
    $('#numero_conos').append($('<option/>', {value: elem, text: elem}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="numero_conos">
</select>
```